# Algebraic definition of Tangent space of manifold.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and a point $m\in M$ denote by $\tilde F_m$ the set of germs of smooth functions at $m$. The tangent space at $m$ (denoted by $M_m$)is defined as the space of linear derivations on the algebra $\tilde F_m$. An isomorphism can then be established between $M_m$ and the space $(F_m/F_m^2)^*$, where $F_m$ is the ideal defined by $F_m:=\lbrace f\in\tilde F_m|f(m)=0\rbrace$. Here comes my question. Since the derivations on $F_m$ are precisely those linear functionals vanishing on $F_m^2$ and at germs of constant functions, it seems more natural to me to define the tangent space as $(\tilde F_m/(F_m^2\oplus C))^*$ where $C$ denotes the subalgebra of germs of constant functions. Would this work? I don't have an intuition behind the $(F_m/F_m^2)^*$ definition unfortunately. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What criteria do you expect to be satisfied for «this to work»?

Comment: When you quotient $\tilde{F}_m$ by the constant functions, you get $F_m$ since you are just modifying the constant term of your function to make it vanish at your point. So what you are proposing is the same as the usual definition.

Comment: @Mariano: I simply said that because it is possible that I have made some ridiculous mistake. Like I often do :)

Comment: @sanchez: Unfortunately, it is not obvious to me why they are equivalent. Quotient structures are something I am still a bit new to.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki, there is an isomorphism theorem that says $A/B \cong (A/C)/(B/C)$. Take $A$ to be your $\tilde{F}_m$, $B = F_m^2 + C$, $C$ to be your $C$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $(U,\varphi)$ is a coordinate chart around $p \in M$, where $M$ smooth manifold, then how does $\varphi$ induce coordinates on $T_p M$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031496/if-u-varphi-is-a-coordinate-chart-around-p-in-m-where-m-smooth-manifo)